# sqlite count the number of consecutive matching rows while excluding them

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, case, window-functions

#### Update

I'm still open to other suggestions even though there's an accepted answer. I need this to work on sqlite going back to at least version `3.19.4` (effectively Android 8), and the most performant form of the accepted answer (using window functions) is not available before version `3.28` of sqlite. The fallbacks cause the device to stall and then crash when the table being queried contains hundreds of rows, so I can't rely on those.

---

#### Original question

Consider that I have a sqlite table called `messages` with these columns:

```
| id | type | text | time |
---------------------------
```

`id` is the primary key and is unique. Imagine that I have 5 rows in the following order (representing them as a JSON array for clarity):

```js
[
  {
    id: 'first',
    type: 'random',
    text: 'hey there',
    time: '2022-02-15T01:47:25.581'
  },
  {
    id: 'second',
    type: 'new_item',
    text: 'new shoe',
    time: '2022-02-15T01:48:25.581'
  }
  {
    id: 'third',
    type: 'new_item',
    text: 'new socks',
    time: '2022-02-15T01:49:25.581'
  }
  {
    id: 'fourth',
    type: 'random',
    text: 'what time is it',
    time: '2022-02-15T01:50:25.581'
  },
  {
    id: 'fifth',
    type: 'new_item',
    text: 'new shoe',
    time: '2022-02-15T01:51:25.581'
  }
```

I want to query these messages such that consecutive rows with type of `new_item` are represented as one, as well as the number of consecutive rows that are present for each unique `new_item` in the final output. Concretely, I would like output that gives me the information captured below (doesn't have to be the same schema, this is just an example of what I want):

```js
[
  {
    id: 'first',
    type: 'random',
    text: 'hey there',
    time: '2022-02-15T01:47:25.581'
  },
  {
    id: 'second',
    type: 'new_item',
    text: 'new shoe',
    time: '2022-02-15T01:48:25.581',
    numConsecutiveItems: 2
  }
  {
    id: 'fourth',
    type: 'random',
    text: 'what time is it',
    time: '2022-02-15T01:50:25.581'
  },
  {
    id: 'fifth',
    type: 'new_item',
    text: 'new shoe',
    time: '2022-02-15T01:51:25.581',
    numConsecutiveItems: 1
  }
```

Notice that the message with id of `third` is not in the final output because it has type of `new_item` and consecutively follows another message with type `new_item`, and the message with id of `second` has `numConsecutiveItems` of `2` for the same reason. More so, the message with id of `fifth` is present because it doesn't immediately follow another `new_item` message, and its value of `numConsecutiveItems` is `1` for the same reason. Can I achieve this with a single query, and ordered by the `time` column? That will be my strong preference, but if not then ideally no more than 2 queries. Thank you!

Comment: Table-like sample data and expected results are much easier to use in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window functions to create the groups of consecutive types and count how many of them are `'new_item'` in each group:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) count,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY time) rn 
  FROM (       
    SELECT *, SUM(flag) OVER (ORDER BY time) grp
    FROM (
      SELECT *, (type <> LAG(type, 1, '') OVER (ORDER BY time)) flag
      FROM tablename
    )
  )  
)
SELECT id, type, text, time,
       CASE WHEN type = 'new_item' THEN count END numConsecutiveItems
FROM cte
WHERE numConsecutiveItems IS NULL OR rn = 1
ORDER BY time;
```

For versions of SQLite that do not support window functions, use aggregations and correlated subqueries to simulate the window functions:

```
WITH 
  prev_types AS (
    SELECT t1.*, t1.type <> COALESCE(t2.type, '') flag, MAX(t2.time) max_time 
    FROM tablename t1 LEFT JOIN tablename t2
    ON t2.time < t1.time
    GROUP BY t1.id
  ),
  sum_flags AS (
    SELECT pt1.*, SUM(pt2.flag) grp
    FROM prev_types pt1 INNER JOIN prev_types pt2
    ON pt2.time <= pt1.time
    GROUP BY pt1.id
  ),
  cte AS (
    SELECT sf1.*, 
           (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sum_flags sf2 WHERE sf2.grp = sf1.grp) count,
           (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sum_flags sf2 WHERE sf2.grp = sf1.grp AND sf2.time <= sf1.time) rn
    FROM sum_flags sf1
  )
SELECT id, type, text, time,
       CASE WHEN type = 'new_item' THEN count END numConsecutiveItems
FROM cte
WHERE numConsecutiveItems IS NULL OR rn = 1
ORDER BY time;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=010b9389d2664ddecf09a0f810aa2581).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the detailed answer and the demo as well. I've gotten it to work in the fiddle but it's not working where I need it, which is in an android app built with [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/). Are you aware of any reason why this wouldn't work with sqlite on Android? The error I'm getting says `near \"(\": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling` the operation you provided.

Comment: Cordova relies on plugins that link to native functionality that's provided by the native code of the device, so Java in the case of Android. I'm not sure if the problem is the sqlite plugin I'm using, but I posted about this error on the plugin's github repo so if you want to take a look it's [here](https://github.com/storesafe/cordova-sqlite-storage/issues/1001)

Comment: @UcheOzoemena I don't know about Cordova, but I know that Android before API level 30 uses a version of SQLite that does not support window functions.

Comment: Oh wow :(, that's a big caveat for my use case. Is there a way to polyfill the functionality? Or do you know of another way to achieve this grouping and counting?

Comment: @UcheOzoemena check my 2nd query which works for earlier versions of SQLite, but you should know that the performance in this case would not be that good.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm now getting a different error on the device: `misuse of aggregate: SUM() (code 1)`. I tried researching it but the suggestions didn't seem to be applicable. And the variations I tried threw other errors. I created [another fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5bd9f20b80e4cc6b76f6bfb0d5e2324c) that's a closer representation of my real data, so please have a look here and let me know what you think. It's like before, the operation works in the fiddle but fails on the device.

Comment: @UcheOzoemena the 2nd query works for SQLite versions 3.8.3+, so there is no version problem. The error that you get is not thrown by my code. You would get an error like that if you tried to nest aggregate functions like SUM(SUM(...)), something that does not exist in my queries.

Comment: Okay I see, hmm. I didn’t add any new queries or operations, it’s really just the columns names and some values that changed.

Comment: @UcheOzoemena I reproduced the error that you get in version 3.20.1 (but I can't explain it so maybe it is a bug that was fixed in later versions). I made a change which you can check: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=21bd411575b67f9b4948a1b1c92e3026

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for the different suggestions. I'll need to find  a way to detect the sqlite version that's running on the phone and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Is it possible for this operation to stall the sqlite driver in some way? It appears the query can make sqlite unresponsive in the app. Might that be the performance concern you mentioned?

Comment: It seems that's exactly what's happening. When I have 5 rows in the table the operation works. But with 2005 rows I get no response. So somewhere in the middle a limit is exceeded. Is there a way to further optimize the query to avoid this?

Comment: Also if I remove the requirement of knowing the count of consecutive items can the query be made more performant? So basically if I need the same output in my question but without the `numConsecutiveItems` property, can the query be changed to make it more performant?

Comment: @UcheOzoemena As I mentioned in one of my earlier comments, a query that does not use window functions would perform worse. Unfortunately Android does not allow the use of window functions before API level 30. What you could do that may (or not) improve performance, is to create an index on the column date, something like: `CREATE INDEX idx_msg_date ON chatMessages(date);`. I believe that you already have defined `id` as the primary key of the table. For a query without `numConsecutiveItems` check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c2eaab5f97e11ff662e66dab2a0c68de